# Unable to build framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks

I am unable to build a framework doing following->
1.Select a simulator in run devices
2.Under Product -> build in Xcode tool bar
3.Right click on the product section  ->show in finder [image: got Debug-iphone folder as shown in figure]

4. now in terminal I execute following command->
       lipo -info /path/to/debugfolder/
   it gives me follwing error -

> fatal error: /Applications/Xcode
>   app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo:
>   can't map input file:
>   /Users/Imacshubhendra/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SendOTPFramework-hkrvnvttlmwijudmlfcaxdowqhpz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SendOTPFramework.framework
>   (Invalid argument)

I am follwing these steps->
In the framework project:

Set the build setting for the target (and for the project, just to be safe) 'Build Active Architectures only' to NO. We want to build all architectures so that the binary can be used in all supported devices, not just the one we happen to build for. Depending on your deployment target (and as a consequence of that, the devices you support), you might need to add the architecture ARMv7s
Build for simulator and build for device, this will produce two frameworks in the derived data folder.
In Terminal:

Find the derived data path for the project. Look for the folder 'Build->Products'. Inside it should be '-iphoneos' and '-iphonesimulator'. Inside each is a .framework folder. Copy one of those to some nice folder. From each of those .frawework folders, copy the binary that is in there to one folder.
In terminal run the command 'lipo -create -output   '. This will create a fat binary with all architectures for both simulator and devices. Replace the one in the copied .framework directory with the newly generated one.
To use the framework in another app:

Select the Project in the Project Navigator, select the target, and select 'General' tab.
drag the .framework folder onto where it says 'Add embedded binaries here'.
In the build settings of the target, add the path to the .framework folder to 'Framework Search Paths'.
Import files in your source code using #import

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do it?

Comment: check the answer jameson